# filter from dplyr: where two string columns need to be compared along with numeric

Tags: r, string, filter, dplyr, numeric

I need to apply the filter condition on String columns along with numeric columns. This way it is not giving the expected output. If anyone has encountered the same problem, please help

```
Num1<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
Num2<-c(1,2,2,1,1)
String1<-c("AA","BB","CC","DD","EE")
String2<-c("AA","BB","CC","DD","FF")
data<-c(Num1,Num2,String1,String2)
df<-data%>%
filter((Num2<Num1) & (String1==String2))
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided an example of what you want to accomplish along with the desired output and data. Please refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to create a `data.frame` instead of a `vector`

```
data<- data.frame(Num1,Num2,String1,String2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

and then the OP would work

```
data %>%
    filter(Num2 < Num1 & String1 == String2)
#   Num1 Num2 String1 String2
#1    3    2      CC      CC
#2    4    1      DD      DD
```